# Unsupported Media Type error when making a post into a REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, postman

I have a REST API built with `Spring-boot`. I want to perform a post request using postman, but I'm getting the error "Unsupported Media Type". I guess is related with the JSON, which should be bad form, but I can't imagine why. This is my JSON object:

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Jonh",
    "pass": "464d83f2a73cc7068632fb46cbb0214538dec819",
    "typeOfSubscription": "TRIAL_VERSION",
    "partiesRemainingThisMonth": 1,
    "subscriptionEndDate": 2458078,
    "parties": []
}
```

And this are the variables that I have defined of the object on the API:

```
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String pass;
private TypeOfSubscription typeOfSubscription;
private Integer partiesRemainingThisMonth;
private Date subscriptionEndDate;
private List<Party> parties;
```

`TypeOfSubscription` is a enum with the following values:

```
NO_SUBSCRIPTION(0, 0, 0),
TRIAL_VERSION(1, 1, 1),
ONE_MONTH(2, 3, 1),
THREE_MONTHS(3, 5, 3),
SIX_MONTHS(4, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 6);

private Integer id;
private Integer partiesPerMonth;
private Integer subscriptionMonths;
```

I don't find out why it's failing because the JSON looks good built. I suspect that the enum is involved, or maybe the date (I'm using Julian format).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide screenshot of postman , from where you are sending the request. and what is the response.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that you have any headers set.  You'll want to set the header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Nope, I have these header setted